How to handle None values for condition_input in a CrossAttention block in PyTorch?
I am working on implementing a cross-attention block in a transformer using PyTorch. My code works fine when condition_input is provided, but it raises an error when condition_input is None. What are the best techniques to handle this situation? For example, x can be image data, and condition_input can be text. If possible, please provide reference.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import math

class CrossAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim=512, block_size=16, n_head=8, drop_out_rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        assert embed_dim % 8 == 0
        # key, query, value projections for all heads
        self.key = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        self.query = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        self.value = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)

        self.attn_drop = nn.Dropout(drop_out_rate)
        self.resid_drop = nn.Dropout(drop_out_rate)

        self.proj = nn.Linear(embed_dim, embed_dim)
        # causal mask to ensure that attention is only applied to the left in the input sequence
        self.register_buffer("mask", torch.tril(torch.ones(block_size, 77)).view(1, 1, block_size, 77))
        self.n_head = n_head

    def forward(self, x, condition_input=None):
        B, T, C = x.size()
                
        B, N, D = condition_input.size()
        
        # Calculate query, key, values for all heads in batch and move head forward to be the batch dim
        k = self.key(condition_input).view(B, N, self.n_head, C // self.n_head).transpose(1, 2)  # (B, nh, N, hs)
        q = self.query(x).view(B, T, self.n_head, C // self.n_head).transpose(1, 2)       # (B, nh, T, hs)
        v = self.value(condition_input).view(B, N, self.n_head, C // self.n_head).transpose(1, 2) # (B, nh, N, hs)
        
        # Causal self-attention; Self-attend: (B, nh, T, hs) x (B, nh, hs, N) -> (B, nh, T, N)
        att = (q @ k.transpose(-2, -1)) * (1.0 / math.sqrt(k.size(-1)))
        att = F.softmax(att, dim=-1)
        att = self.attn_drop(att)
        y = att @ v  # (B, nh, T, N) x (B, nh, N, hs) -> (B, nh, T, hs)
        y = y.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(B, T, C)  # Re-assemble all head outputs side by side

        # Output projection
        y = self.resid_drop(self.proj(y))
        return y


# Example usage:
cross_attention = CrossAttention()
x = torch.randn(4, 10, 512)  # Example input tensor
output = cross_attention(x)  # Pass x without 'condition_input'
print(output.shape)

Current Error
When condition_input is None, the code produces an error
Desired Behavior
I would like to modify the CrossAttention block so that it can still run when condition_input is None. How can I achieve this?

I am going to throw in a large "it depends" without knowing much about what you are trying to mitigate here. What is your input? How often do you expect it to be None? Is it going to be None most of the time or some of the time? If it is the former then I would guess you want to use Self Attention, if it is only at times then assign it a default tensor. But my question is do you understand what's happening in the forward pass clearly and what it means in the attention mechanism or are you just here because you saw an error and need a value to "just get over" it, regardless try the suggestion

The code as written computes attention between x and condition_input. Given that setup, condition_input cannot be None. You can't compute cross attention without something to cross-attend to.

Yes, I am completely familiar with cross-attention and self-attention. This block runs multiple times. In the first iteration, there is no condition_input (text), but in subsequent iterations, there is always a condition_input (text). My idea is to define an nn.Parameter(torch.randn()) in the __init__ method, and in the forward method, use that if condition_input is None. If condition_input is not None, then everything is fine. I asked this question to see if there are other methods that I am not aware of.
